# How to fix intellisense autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

**Visual Studio Code Version:** 1.47.3

I was making javascript and typescript projects non-stop for about 5 months now. Until a week ago the vscode intellisense was perfect. 
But now, is really bad. Not even the node suggestions are being shown anymore, i have to install @types/node in every project that i have to adjust.

For example, none suggestions from the render destructuring are been shown and i couldn't make it work:

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
//...
const { x } = render(<SignIn />);
```

Until last week they were working perfectly. This slows down my productivity a lot. 
I updated all packages, vscode certainly was included.

Since i didn't saw nothing on the vscode issues and nothing here, i'm assuming the problem is my ignorance and not the versioning. 
Why this is happening? Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue a few months back. Try to follow steps(`#3` Worked for me)

1. Try disabling [all the extensions](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Performance-Issues#run-with-extensions-disabled) and see if it's working. If then the problem is with one/more of your extensions.
2. Try to reproduce in the [latest VS Code insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/) build with [all extensions disabled](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Performance-Issues#run-with-extensions-disabled). If you are able to reproduce the issue there, go and create [issue on vscode's github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues)
3. If both `1` and `2` doesn't work delete `C:\Users\<your user>\AppData\Roaming\Code`(Windows) and for Mac `Cmd+Space` type `~/Library/Application Support`, delete `code` directory.

[Github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/86806)

Comment: 1 and 2 didn't work, i am searching for the equivalent folder in linux to delete and try the step 3.

Comment: Which Linux flavor you are using?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS