# Maven dependency : Failed to get sources. Instead, stub sources have been generated by the disassembler

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code

when i'm navigating to a maven dependency class, i get a .class file with this comment on top and no doc is shown :

*// Failed to get sources. Instead, stub sources have been generated by the disassembler.

// Implementation of methods is unavailable.*

I don't have the issue with Java classes, only maven dependencies.

I have enabled download sources in the maven settings.xml and in the java extension pack settings.

Anyone has any idea how to solve this please ?

Answer (score 5):

i had the same problem and i solve it,try this:

1. set settings.json in vscode,
   "java.eclipse.downloadSources": true,"java.maven.downloadSources": true
2. add follow settings in settings.xml of maven:

```
<settings>
    <!-- ... other settings omitted ... -->
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>downloadSources</id>
            <properties>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <activeProfiles>
            <activeProfile>downloadSources</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

3.reopen vscode and it will download javadoc

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to set the `"java.jdt.ls.java.home"` manually? Set it to the JDK you installed on your computer.

Some people others had run across [this kind of problem](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/2277). It looks like an issue with the language server's embedded JRE.

Comment: Thank you for your response, my issue is not with the Java classes, the JDK works fine, the issue is rather with the maven dependencies, it seems that sources are not downloaded

Comment: @tanjamado It looks like a problem with the `Java Language Server`'s embedded JRE, so I suggest you set the JRE of the language server manually. Could you have a try of it? thanks.

Comment: thank you for your response @Steven-MSFT, how do you do that ? I have already set the JAVA_HOME which is pointing to the jdk

Comment: @tanjamado Add the setting of "java.jdt.ls.java.home" in the settings.json.

Comment: Oh okay, I already have that :/

Comment: @tanjamado Does it work?

Comment: no it doesn't :(

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue previously, and I couldn't change the language server's embedded JRE due the version being <17. The fix was adding the following line into `settings.json`.

```
"maven.terminal.useJavaHome": true
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me: I made the following addition on `settings.json` file:

```json
"java.configuration.runtimes": [
    {
        "name": "JavaSE-17",
        "path": "/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/"
    }
]
```

I obtained the location of both the `settings.json` file and the Java `path` from [Henry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74369626/4072641)'s answer. The solution itself was derived from this [GitHub comment](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/2277#issuecomment-1365450613).