# Failed to get sources when debugging multi module maven project in vscode

Tags: maven, visual-studio-code, debugging

I managed to open a multi-module maven project in VS Code and set up the `launch.json` correctly. I can debug the project and the breakpoints are respected in the main module. When I set a breakpoint in a referenced module, the execution will break, but I see a decompiled version of the class with the following comments:

```
 // Failed to get sources. Instead, stub sources have been generated by the disassembler.
 // Implementation of methods is unavailable.
```

I added the plugin in `pom.xml` for that module to generate the source from maven and the source. Then I used `mvn clean install` and the source code JAR was generated successfully under the `target` folder for the specific module.

I tried to launch the debug again, and nothing worked. I still see the decompiled version of the class.

I configured `"sourcePaths"` in `launch.json` to point to the generated source JAR and it didn't and didn't work. I tried to point to the folder, relative path, absolute path, and with/without the filename, but nothing worked.

I appreciate your help to find a resolution to this issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maven dependency : Failed to get sources. Instead, stub sources have been generated by the disassembler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71825911/maven-dependency-failed-to-get-sources-instead-stub-sources-have-been-genera)

Comment: I'll check it out when I'll come across this issue in the future. Thank you.